# Comparing Lists of Hashes for Document Similarity / Clustering

Tags: java, algorithm, similarity

I am taking the following approach to computing similarity between multiple text file documents:

1. For each document in a given directory, break the document into chunks (long sequences of bytes computed from a Basic Sliding Window algorithm).
2. Calculate a fingerprint for each chunk, i.e. hash the chunk using a hash algorithm such as MD5
3. Compare chunks occurring in different files

So far, I have implemented the first two steps.  I am using Google Guava's MultiMap to associate hashed chunks with file names. As for step 3, I am now looking to do the following:

```
For each file {
   get the file's hashed chunks
   compare the hashed chunks with those of every other file
}
```

The idea here is to compare ﬁle signatures for common entries and report only clusters of those ﬁles whose signature intersection is above a given similarity threshold. But I ultimately want to tweak this logic to get a similarity score for each file as it is compared to a source file.

**My question:** What is the best way to compare hashed chunks for step 3? Also, how can I incorporate the concept of similarity with the former? Here is my code thus far:

```
public class ContentBasedChunkingMain implements Similarity {

    Multimap<String, byte[]> hashMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    public ContentBasedChunkingMain() {
    }

    @Override
    public void getSimilarity(String dir) {

        // Document directory
        File directory = new File(dir);

        Collection<File> collection = FileUtils.listFiles(directory,
                TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);

        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(collection
                .toArray(new File[0])));

        // For each file in the directory
        for (File f : files) {

            // Get chunks
            ArrayList<String> chunks = Chunker.getChunks(f);

            for (String s : sentences) {

                // MD5 Hash each sentence
                MD5HashFunction h = new MD5HashFunction();
                System.out.println(h.byteToHex(h.hash(s)));

                // Store filename and hashed chunk into MultiMap
                hashMap.put(f.getAbsolutePath(), h.hash(s));

            }

        }

        // Step 3    
        for (File f : files) {

            // for each file, get the file's hashed chunks
            Collection<byte[]> bytes = hashMap.get(f.getAbsolutePath());

            // compare ...

        }

    }
```

The algorithm that I am following, Content-Based Chunking Algorithm, is described in more detail in the following papers:

http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2009/HPL-2009-90.pdf

http://webglimpse.net/pubs/TR93-33.pdf

http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-42R1.pdf

Comment: Comparing hashes will determine only if two chunks are _identical_ or not. Even a single bit difference will result in completely different hash values.  This method will not establish any similarity between individual chunks. Say you chunked by "sentence" as you describe.  Two documents containing the same sentences with slightly different punctuation or spelling in each sentence would compare as completely different using this approach.

Comment: It should be possible by breaking the text of a document into smaller pieces and comparing how many of those (hashed) pieces are the same between multiple documents, no? See the three papers that I referenced at the bottom of the post.

Comment: The original algorithm calls for chunks being long sequences, computed via a Basic Sliding Window algorithm. I'm merely using sentences for now as I implement the algorithm...sort of a "walk before you run" mentality.

Comment: The hashed values can only be compared as `equal or different`. If two hashes are not the same, there is no way to compute how different their original texts are (and of course, you may end that even when two hashes are the same the texts are different, but that should be rare enough).

Comment: What you might want to check is, from two sequences of hashes, which subsequences do match. There were some algorithms for String comparation/conversion from one String into another that might be useful, but I do not recall their name.

Comment: OK, the crucial piece of information here is the "sliding window", in which you calculate hashes for **overlapping** text segments.  This completely changes the picture from "can't possibly work" to "might work depending on how you chunk".  The key point is the overlapping text windows.

Comment: OK Jim, I'll work "Basic Sliding Window" into my original post for clarification.

Comment: This might be useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance, or this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the comparison, I took the intersection of the two hash chunk collections.